# In webview fonts like (Tamil,Telugu,Hindi) not working on android version above 5.0

Tags: android, webview

In `webview`, fonts like (Tamil,Telugu,Hindi) are not working on Android versions above 5.0 but the same URL is working perfectly in chrome browser and below Android version 5.0.

[image: image description here]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: share your code

Comment: please code you have written so far. if you are using html file from assets. you have to give font with your css @font-face {
  font-family:Mangal;
  src: url("file:///android_asset/Fonts/mangal.ttf")
  }
  body {
  font-family:Mangal;
  }

Comment: Am loading the thirdparty url in webview..need to show 10 fonts(tamil,hindi,kannada etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Chrome custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) to get native behaviour same as google chrome.
This may solve your problem

Comment: Webview is not a good option anymore, you should use custom tabs it gives you same experience as google chrome within your application.

Comment: Thanks abdul,is there any option to hide/mask  the url which is showing  in the tool bar.

Comment: No You can not hide tool bar. All you can do is to hide it from web for mobile  view

Comment: if we disable the chrome app in mobile that time this feature not working..app getting crashed..kindly suggest..

Comment: sure..but how to do chat

Comment: we can talk here, if your comments exceeds limit, we will automatically go for chat

Comment: if we disable the chrome app in mobile that time this feature not working..app getting crashed..kindly suggest.

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.bharatmatrimony, PID: 14126
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxyy/com.xxyy.WebViewActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.xxyyyy.com/... (has extras) }